# AttributeError: 'TimeStep' object has no attribute 'time_step_spec'

Tags: lstm, reinforcement-learning, dqn

How to fix that atributeerror for LSTM ?

File "run.py", line 13, in 
from TraderEnv import TraderEnv
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\TraderEnv.py", line 424, in 
lstm_state_eval_policy = LSTMStatePolicy(agent.policy, lstm_size)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\TraderEnv.py", line 377, in **init**
super().**init**(policy.time_step_spec,
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\new_env\lib\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1605, in gin_wrapper
utils.augment_exception_message_and_reraise(e, err_str)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\new_env\lib\site-packages\gin\utils.py", line 41, in augment_exception_message_and_reraise
raise proxy.with_traceback(exception.**traceback**) from None
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\new_env\lib\site-packages\gin\config.py", line 1582, in gin_wrapper
return fn(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\RL-Forex-trader-LSTM-master\new_env\lib\site-packages\tf_agents\policies\py_tf_eager_policy.py", line 127, in **init**
time_step_spec = tensor_spec.to_nest_array_spec(policy.time_step_spec)
AttributeError: 'TimeStep' object has no attribute 'time_step_spec'
In call to configurable 'PyTFEagerPolicy' (<class 'tf_agents.policies.py_tf_eager_policy.PyTFEagerPolicy'>)

trying to pass LSTM for DQN agent